# Identify the parameter causing the anomaly in a multivariate dataset

Tags: svm, autoencoders, anomaly-detection, k-nearest-neighbour, isolation-forest

I have a payment transaction dataset with a large number of predictor variables. I am trying to build a model for anomaly detection and I have evaluated various algorithms/approaches for the same like Isolation Forest, kNN, Autoencoders, and One-class SVM.

I am able to identify if a payment record is an anomaly or not but I am not able to pin-point the predictor variable that is causing the anomaly.

e.g.:

### Account  ||  Currency  ||  Beneficiary  ||  Amount ||  isAnomaly(target)

I want to identify if, for an anomalous record, **Currency** variable is causing the anomaly or **Amount** variable is causing the anomaly.

I have gone through the below sources amongst many others but couldn't find anything helpful.

[Anomaly detection with a multivariate Gaussian vs. PCA + univariate Gaussians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89650/anomaly-detection-with-a-multivariate-gaussian-vs-pca-univariate-gaussians)

[Use case for Anomaly Detection using the multivariate Gaussian distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215082/use-case-for-anomaly-detection-using-the-multivariate-gaussian-distribution)

[Anomaly detection in multivariate time series data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378064/anomaly-detection-in-multivariate-time-series-data)

[Anomaly Detection in multiple parameters](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/anomaly-detection-in-multiple-parameters?rq=1)

I have recently started my journey in data science and would be glad if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620108/finding-source-of-cause-in-anomaly-detection